# "Specified cast is not valid" for DataTable.Compute?

Tags: c#, casting, datatable

I have this code here:

```
decimal dec = (decimal)MyDataTable.Compute("Min(Rooms)", string.Empty);
```

It always tells me **Specified cast is not valid**. How could I check if the Compute will succedd at runtime?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
object dec = MyDataTable.Compute("Min(Rooms)", string.Empty);
decimal d;
bool result = Decimal.TryParse(dec.ToString(), out d);
```

if `result` is `true` it means parse was successful

Comment: Decimal.TryParse(dec) needs at least 2 params?

Comment: The second parameter is the out(put) parameter, so the parse result has a place to go (since the actual return value of the method is the boolean success/failure indicator).

Comment: @grady - see my answer on why you need 2.

Comment: You can try this  `Decimal.TryParse(MyDataTable.Compute("Min(Rooms)", string.Empty).ToString(), out d);`

Comment: yes I agree it happens sometimes but I guess what matters is which answer makes more sense to the reader

Comment: Yes I have and I do where it is appropriate but here I didn't see your answer before posting mine so I don't think I awe it you here

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `Decimal.TryParse()` See if that helps you. 
[Here is the msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx)
This should work:

```
        var s = "123.34";
        decimal d;

        bool isDec = Decimal.TryParse(s, out d);

        if (isDec)
            Console.WriteLine("It was a decimal: " + d);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Not a decimal!");

        Console.WriteLine(isDec);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

The reason you need two parameters is the first parameter is a representation of the decimal in string format.  If TryParse succeeds the result is stored in `d` (in the above example).  In this above example `isDec` prints `true`.